# node.js mongoose required: true not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm making an application with node.js and using mongoose. I'm using a very simple form with 1 input field which I set to "required: true" so it cannot be blank when its posted.

Yet its still possible to post the empty input field and it will redirect you to the the /author page while it should stay on the /authors/new page because the post should have been invalid.

This is my author.js file in the models directory:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Auhtor', authorSchema)
```

and this is the auhtors.js file in the routes directory:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Author = require('../models/author')

//all author route
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('authors/index')
})

// new author route
router.get('/new',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('authors/new', {author: new Author()})
})

// create author
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const author = new Author({
        name: req.body.name
    })
    author.save((err, newAuthor)=>{  
        if(err){      
            let locals = { errorMessage: "something went wrong"}
            res.render('authors/new',{
                locals:locals,
                author: author         
            })
            
        } else{
            // res.redirect(`author/${newAuthor.id}`)
            res.redirect(`authors`)
        }
    })    
})
    
module.exports = router
```

Comment: Print and check the value of **req.body.name**

Comment: Also - this may be only a typo here and not in your code, but your model.exports name is 'Auhtor', not Author.